# Why am I getting this error display for my video in Chrome?

Tags: html, video, tags, syntax-error

When I run this code in Chrome:

```html
<html>
<head><title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="100" height="100" controls>
<source src="G:\Users\tanmay\Documents\Apowersoft\ApowerREC\20180923_112116.mp4" type=video\mp4>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

the following display is seen:

[image]

Comment: Referenced file doesn't exist, obviously

Comment: Does it only happen in Chrome or do you get an error in other browsers as well?

Comment: And link format is wrong

Comment: Also try `type="video/mp4"` as mime types have forward slashes, not backslashes. In fact, I think you should be using forward slashes even in your filenames, too (but I am not sure about that one, as I know Windows uses backslashes, but I think forward slashes are acceptable.)

Comment: @tanmay if the posted Answer works correctly then mark as solved by clicking the big `✓` icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your link format is wrong.

- Add `file:///` in front of your drive letter since not from web (*eg:* is not `http://`).
- Browsers use the Unix style `/` for slashes, not the Microsoft/Windows `\` style.

```html
<html>
<head><title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="100" height="100" controls>
<source src="file:///G:/Users/tanmay/Documents/Apowersoft/ApowerREC/20180923_112116.mp4" type=video/mp4>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Try to use above code.Hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In future, try to explain how or why it works (where possible).